# Recursion clarification

Tags: java, recursion

I just wanted to make sure that I was completely solid on recursion. I have used it in a bunch of applications, but realized that when someone asked me to define it (a newer programmer asked this), I was a bit shaky on the definition and had a bit of trouble explaining it. I just wanted to reach out to a large programming community to make sure I was on the right track.

From what I know, recursion in computer science is when some answers to a given problem or check (i.e. an if statement) depend on something else related to the same method. A way to solve this could be a function calling on itself (which the majority of programming languages support). I wrote a simple Fibonacci program below:

```
public int fib(int n) {
    if(n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Let me know if I'm on the right track. Also, I am aware that there are similar questions on recursion, but please do not close this question as a duplicate because this is a more general question not limited to a specific language, but more a concept on what recursion is.

Thanks,

brld

Comment: recursive function is a function using itself. you can see deeper with tail recursion and how the compiler can rewrite it as a loop. recursive method can often be loops.

Comment: You're over thinking it.  Recursion is when a function/method calls itself.

Comment: While you don't understand recursion, read this sentence from the beginning.

Comment: Recursion is when a method calls itself. Done. That's it. If a method calls itself it uses recursion, and if it doesn't then it doesn't,

Comment: There is no specific question here.

Comment: To clarify: recursion isn't only when a method calls itself directly (like `fib` calling `fib` in your example).  It also includes cases when method A calls some other methods B, C, etc., which could call other methods, D, E, ..., but then if any of those call A, you have recursion.  A is calling A, but indirectly.

Comment: One other thing to understand about recursion: it's a terrible way to program if you can accomplish the same thing with a simple loop.  It's especially bad for computing Fibonacci numbers.  Using a loop runs in linear time, but using recursion as in your example runs in exponential time.

Comment: @ajb Depends on the implementation. For instance, Fibonacci numbers with memoization runs in linear time for the first evaluation of `fib(n)`, and constant time thereafter for all values less than or equal to a previously calculated `n`.

Comment: @pjs Right, but memoization would add lots of complexity.  It doesn't make the recursive solution look any better.

Comment: @ajb Really?  You think [this](https://gist.github.com/PaulSanchez/729cdba3eb9d5858f18d2e76f6f6e40f) is lots of complexity?

Comment: @pjs Actually, yes.  It's nice and short, but it actually takes some study to convince oneself that it isn't going to crash.  Note that `memo.add(n, value)` only works if `n <= memo.size`, otherwise it throws an exception.  So you start with `memo.size == 2`, and (say) `n == 20`, and then the method tests `20 > 2`, and then it looks like you're going to try to insert at position 20 into a 2-element `ArrayList`, which doesn't work, until you realize that evaluating the second parameter will happen to increase the `ArrayList` to the right size.....

Comment: @pjs Thus I'd call this complex because it's difficult to read--I'd call it tricky.  A readable version would probably involve a hash table rather than an `ArrayList`.  OK, maybe that wouldn't be "lots" of complexity, but either this or the `ArrayList` means adding another data structure to a problem that shouldn't require one.  I still say this doesn't make recursion look good.

Comment: @ajb Any Java programmer should know that `ArrayList` is dynamically resizable, and that the `add` will work just fine.  The result being added is just the recursive definition of Fibonacci.  Hence I disagree with your opinion on the matter.

Comment: @pjs `ArrayList` is dynamically resizable, yes, but `add` will increase the list size by 1; it cannot be used to increase it more than that.  That's why it isn't obvious that this code works.  Supposing you were using the same tactic to implement a slightly different function in which the key line is `memo.add(n, foob(n-2) + foob(n-3));`.  That would fail.

Comment: @ajb Not so, `add` with an index expands as needed and adds the object at the specified index.  Again, people familiar with Java and `ArrayList` should know this, or look it up in seconds.  It would behave the same with your `foob` example as long as the base case was defined to contain the first 3 elements, same as with a non-memoized implementation.

Comment: @pjs Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-.  `memo.add(n,value)` throws an exception if `n > memo.size()`.  And I tested my `foob` example and it indeed threw an exception just as I said it would.

Comment: @ajb My mistake on the `add`, been working primarily in Ruby rather than Java for several years now.  Regardless, the Fibonacci works and I maintain it is readable for people used to the concepts of recursion and memoization, and darned efficient from an amortized perspective with repeated use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.  I would break this up into pieces:

1. Definition: By dictionary definition, recursion is a a process calling itself.  This call is usually direct, as in your example, but can also be indirect: f1 and f2 call each other, but not themselves.
2. Example: Just as you did ... show a well-known function with an easily understood recursive definition.  I usually use factorial, since it has only one recursive call; then I present the Fibonacci case.
3. Mechanics: Describe the critical properties of base case (what makes it stop, at last) and simplification (reduce the problem before you recur).
4. Proper use: Pretty much any real programming application with a recursive description will have an iterative (looping) solution that takes less computing time.  However, if the *natural* description is recursive, it's quite possible that the most *efficient* solution *in the long run* is recursive.  Consider repair and maintenance resources in addition to mere execution cycles, and remember that FLOPS get cheaper every month.

Comment: Nice answer, although I disagree to some extent with your point #4.  You can implement non-recursive solutions to inherently recursive problems but in some cases doing so requires you to maintain an explicit stack for intermediate state info that isn't used immediately.  A few examples:  Towers of Hanoi, tree traversal, recursive descent parsing, having a variable number of nested loops, etc.  In these cases it's simpler and more likely to yield correct results if you write the solution recursively and let the language handle the stack aspects.

Comment: That's what I said: "the most efficient solution in the long run is recursive."  I carry this principle to other paradigms.  In the days before generic sorting algorithms, I often coded an N^2 sort, because I knew that future engineers could easily understand it.

Comment: I understand and agree with that part of what you wrote.  I guess I'm sounding like a broken record here, but I've been trying to make the point to some other respondents that it's a mistake to cast recursion as *just* a variant of looping.