# Practical usage of recursion

Tags: recursion

Is there any practical problems where recursion is either the best solution or even the only solution? Here I imply that developer of real application should handle accompanying issues of stack size, stack overflow etc on target system.

Update:
May be my question was formulated wrong. I know there are problems that could be solved using recursion. However I suppose in real world coder should handle somehow any problems related to recursive solution: stack overflow for example. It may be sophisticated to determine target system parameters. So, e.g., I can suppose that someone should avoid recursion if possible in any complex problems.

Comment: Your extensive research couldn't find *any* such problems?

Comment: Hanoi Towers. Compare recursive and iterative.

Comment: This question is too broad but this might be a good place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call once you can apply recursion without adding new stack frames, the sky is the limit.

Comment: Read about quick-sort, merge-sort, graph traversal, binary search for example.

Comment: Please update your question to include the discussions you found in your research, and explain how they have not satisfied your curiosity.  I've answered it, myself, at least twice under this "recursion" tag.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693080/recursion-clarification/39708087#39708087) is a short version.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean. Recursion, stacks, and trees are intimately related. If we are doing an operation on tree-like data, we must somewhere have a stack which we push and pop and we go up and down the tree.

But it is always possible to move that stack off the call stack in the computer programming language you happen to be using. Often it is far more convenient to simply use the call stack, but some languages don't allow recursive functions, and in C it is impossible to protect the call stack from overflow. But you are not getting rid of the recursion, you are just moving the stack elsewhere.